# Calling a Progressive Web App from another android application is poosible

Tags: asp.net-core, progressive-web-apps

Calling a Progressive Web App from another android application is poosible

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AadharScan(string AadharNumber)
{
var currentTimestamp = System.DateTime.Now;

```
 var pidOptXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
     "<PidOptions ver=\"1.0\" env=\"PP\">\n" +
     "<Opts pidVer=\"2.0\" otp=\"\" wadh=\"\"/>\n" +
     "<CustOpts>\n" +
     "<Param name=\"txnId\" value=\"" + currentTimestamp + "\"/>\n" +
     "</CustOpts>\n" +
     "<BioData/>\n" +
     "</PidOptions>";
 string URL = "in.gov.uidai.rdservice.face.CAPTURE";
 //Intent intentCapture = new Intent(null, ChildApp);
 //callNewmethod(intentCapture);
 //startActivityForResult(intentCapture, "2");


 Intent intent = new Intent();
 NewMethod(intent);
 intent.PutExtra("key2", 42);
 intent.PutExtra("key3", true);



 StartActivity(intent);



 //static void callNewmethod(Intent intentCapture)
 //{
 //    intentCapture.putExtra("request");
 //}


 ////Intent intentCapture1= new Intent("in.gov.uidai.rdservice.face.CAPTURE");
 //intentCapture.putExtra("request", pidOptXml);
 //startActivityForResult(intentCapture, resultCode);

 return View();

 static void NewMethod(Intent intent)
 {
     intent.PutExtra("key1", "value1");
 }
```

}

but some error find PutExtra name space